# Difference between apachectl -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and apachectl start

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, apache2

I'm running Debian 8 Jessie, and [I've got a PHP issue somehow related to my Apache configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958487/php-exececho-hi-tmp-output-txt-is-not-creating-a-file?noredirect=1#comment76917489_44958487).

Running Apache with:

```
apachectl -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Gives the desired results/behavior, while running the traditional way the daemon does, does not:

```
apachectl start
```

How do I go about determining what the differences are between those two options to isolate my problem?

Answer (score 0):

apachectl is a bash script that loads envvars file in the environment and allows manual options and runs the httpd binary with them.

The only difference is if you don't specify the config file, apachectl has the default of the installation as the one that will be used.

Do a `cat apachectl` and see what it has inside. Also you can check the httpd binary options calling it like: `httpd -help` (some distros call it apache2 or similar).